# Recursion not breaking

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve Euler problem 18 where I am required to find out the maximum total from top to bottom. I am trying to use recursion, but am stuck with this.

I guess I didn't state my problem earlier. What I am trying to achieve by recursion is to find the sum of the maximum number path. I start from the top of the triangle, and then check the condition is 7 + findsum() bigger or 4 + findsum() bigger. findsum() is supposed to find the sum of numbers beneath it. I am storing the sum in variable 'result'
The problem is I don't know the breaking case of this recursion function. I know it should break when it has reached the child elements, but I don't know how to write this logic in the program.

```
pyramid=[[0,0,0,3,0,0,0,],
         [0,0,7,0,4,0,0],
         [0,2,0,4,0,6,0],
         [8,0,5,0,9,0,3]]

pos=[0,3]

def downleft(pyramid,pos):#returns down left child
    try:
        return(pyramid[pos[0]+1][pos[1]-1])
    except:return(0)    

def downright(pyramid,pos):#returns down right child
    try:
        return(pyramid[pos[0]+1][pos[1]+1])
    except:
        return(0)   

result=0

def find_max(pyramid,pos):

    global result

    if downleft(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]-1]) > downright(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]+1]):
        new_pos=[pos[0]+1,pos[1]-1]
        result+=downleft(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]-1]) 

    elif downright(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]+1]) > downleft(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]-1]):
        new_pos=[pos[0]+1,pos[1]+1]
        result+=downright(pyramid,pos)+find_max(pyramid,[pos[0]+1,pos[1]+1])

    else :
        return(result)  

find_max(pyramid,pos)
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but if this is a brute force algorithm (I think it is) then I think you can do something much simpler. Try something like `max(map(sum, itertools.product(*listoflists)))`, where in this example `listoflists=[[3], [7, 4], [2,4,6], [8,5,9,3]]]`. It won't tell you which path it took, but you could use a modified sum function for that if needed.

Comment: You don't tell us what goes wrong or anything else that would help us to diagnose the problem (Do you get exceptions/wrong results/programm doesn't terminate/...? What happens, where are you stuck and why?)

Comment: And as sth said: if you want us to help you with the code you give then you need to be more specific about what goes wrong. First of all you should replace the `except:` statement with a more specific one for the exception you want to catch. I think you need `IndexError`.

Comment: Updated with problem details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big part of your problem is that you're recursing *a lot* more than you need to. You should really only ever call `find_max` twice recursively, and you need some base-case logic to stop after the last row.

Try this code:

```
def find_max(pyramid, x, y):
    if y >= len(pyramid):   # base case, we're off the bottom of the pyramid
        return 0            # so, return 0 immediately, without recursing

    left_value = find_max(pyramid, x - 1, y + 1)     # first recursive call
    right_value = find_max(pyramid, x + 1, y + 1)    # second recursive call

    if left_value > right_value:
        return left_value + pyramid[y][x]
    else:
        return right_value + pyramid[y][x]
```

I changed the call signature to have separate values for the coordinates rather than using a tuple, as this made the indexing much easier to write. Call it with `find_max(pyramid, 3, 0)`, and get rid of the global `pos` list. I also got rid of the `result` global (the function returns the result).

This algorithm could benefit greatly from memoization, as on bigger pyramids you'll calculate the values of the lower-middle areas many times. Without memoization, the code may be impractically slow for large pyramid sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I see that you are having trouble with the logic of the code. So let's have a look at that.

1. At each position in the tree you want to make a choice of selecting
   the path *from* this point on that has the highest value. So what
   you do is, you calculate the score of the left path and the score of
   the right path. I see this is something you try in your current code,
   only there are some inefficiencies. You calculate everything
   *twice* (first in the `if`, then in the `elif`), which is very expensive. You should only calculate the values of the children once.
2. You ask for the stopping condition. Well, if you reach the bottom of the tree, what is the score of the path starting at this point? It's just the value in the tree. And that is what you should return at that point.

So the structure should look something like this:

```
function getScoreAt(x, y):
   if at the end: return valueInTree(x, y)

   valueLeft = getScoreAt(x - 1, y + 1)
   valueRight = getScoreAt(x + 1, y + 1)
   valueHere = min(valueLeft, valueRight) + valueInTree(x, y)
   return valueHere
```

Extra hint:
Are you aware that in Python negative indices wrap around to the back of the array? So if you do `pyramid[pos[0]+1][pos[1]-1]` you may actually get to elements like `pyramid[1][-1]`, which is at the other side of the row of the pyramid. What you probably expect is that this raises an error, but it does not.

To fix your problem, you should add explicit bound checks and not rely on `try` blocks (`try` blocks for this is also not a nice programming style).

Comment: I have expanded my comment, because you I see you are having some trouble with the design of the algortithm as well.